# How can I keep Android connected to a Raspberry Pi which doesn't provide Internet?

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I use a [PilotAware](https://www.pilotaware.com/) aircraft electronic conspicuity device from my Android device. This works fine on my tablet but has recently stopped working so well on phones - it repeatedly connects and disconnects.

[image: SkyDemon screenshot showing opposite direction aircraft]

PilotAware works like many other Raspberry Pi based devices in offering a WiFi AP but doesn't necessarily provide upstream Internet access. My phone/tablet connects to the AP to enable my [SkDemon](https://www.skydemon.aero/) moving map app to connect a port providing location and traffic information.

This works as planned on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite, but no longer works on my Google Pixel 4a 5G (Android 13) or my friend's Pixel 2 (Android 11). It used to work in the past. It simply won't stay connected to the AP being as there is no Internet connection:

[image: Animation of WiFi disconnection]

My new Samsung Galaxy A54 seems to fare better as it asks what to do, but I have seen a similar dialog in the past on other devices.

[image: Samsung Galaxy A54 stay connected dialog]

Things I've tried, that don't fix it:

- Disabled Battery > Adaptive preferences > Adaptive charging and Adaptive battery
- Disabled Network & Internet > Adaptive connectivity
- Disabled Mobile data (not really a fix, but worth trying)
- Set a static IP

There must be more use cases where a non-Internet connected AP needs to be accessible from Android.

Comment: Based on a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/tsmtki/comment/j4w9uv7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), you may want to try 1) Disable DHCP 2) Set DNS to `0.0.0.0` 3) at which point you should get the "stay connected?" dialog.